# Adding Ads After First And Second Paragraph of WordPress Post

Tags: php, wordpress, ads, paragraphs

I'm hoping someone can help with this question. I have the following working code below in my functions.php file to put Adsense ads after the first paragraph of each post. I'm hoping someone knows how to tweak this code to enable me to also add another ad after the second paragraph. So, in a nutshell, I want ads after the first and second paragraph.

Thanks.....code below.

```
//Insert ads after first paragraph of single post content.
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads' );
function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {

    $ad_code = '<div>Ads code goes here</div>';

        if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
            return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 1, $content );
    }

    return $content;
}

// Parent Function that makes the magic happen
function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) {
    $closing_p = '</p>';
    $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
    foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {

        if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
        $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
    }

    if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
        $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
    }
}

 return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is the entire code:

```
function prefix_insert_after_paragraph2( $ads, $content ) {
    if ( ! is_array( $ads ) ) {
        return $content;
    }

    $closing_p = '</p>';
    $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );

    foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {
        if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
        }

        $n = $index + 1;
        if ( isset( $ads[ $n ] ) ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $ads[ $n ];
        }
    }

    return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads' );
function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {
    if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
        $content = prefix_insert_after_paragraph2( array(
            // The format is: '{PARAGRAPH_NUMBER}' => 'AD_CODE',
            '1' => '<div>Ad code after FIRST paragraph goes here</div>',
            '2' => '<div>Ad code after SECOND paragraph goes here</div>',
        ), $content );
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the quick repsonse. One more question i forgot to mention. Im trying to use two diffrent ads...one for the first paragraph and the other ad for the second paragraph. I see where to place the first ad code, but where do i place the second ad code?

Comment: *Ignore the previous edit.* Please try the new one and just let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: I'm sorry..I'm a little confused. If you would be so kind, can you post the entire code so I can just add my codes into the div class. I'm a little php challenged :)

Comment: I've updated the answer. Just use that code, alright? Try it out and let me know if it works.

Comment: Hey Sally, it works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help. Take care.

Comment: You're welcome! And I'd appreciate if you could [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) or [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) my answer. =)